# Centering CDATA text from an XML file in your flash application

Tags: xml, flash, cdata

Here's an easy one: how can I center text that I'm loading inside CDATA tags from an XML file into my .swf?

Everything I've tried in terms of  tags and text-align:center divs hasn't worked. Is this possible to do without editing the .fla?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input above - I can appreciate the semantics of the situation, however the simplest way to do this turned out to be:

```
<p align="center">
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-align:center` really should work fine if you use style sheets and HTML text, but `<div>`is not supported.  You can use `<p>`and `<span>`to specify your style classes, among others.  Check out the [AS3 doc for TextField#htmlText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) for a list of all supported HTML tags in ActionScript.

Comment: hmm, I tried putting a centered class in the header styling of the index.html page (where the flash is embedded) and then applying the class to a p wrapper for the content but still nothing.. hmm.. is there a more specific way of applying the style to the flash content or should it have worked that way?

Comment: You flash program needs to know the styles - you can either code them directly by using the StyleSheet class, or load an parse a css file.  This should get you started: http://lucamezzalira.com/2008/12/23/styling-your-text-with-css-in-actionscript-3/